# Jazzy Cannot generate all documentation

Tags: swift, jazzy

I've been having a hard time trying to get more than 10% of the project documented.

These are the commands i've been trying

```
jazzy --min-acl internal
jazzy --min-acl private 

jazzy --min-acl private --author 'me' -x -workspace,<project>.xcworkspace,-scheme,<project>
```

Is there any restriction im not aware of?

It seems to me jazzy only documents 19 files

meanwhile i found out that if i add the files to another target, jazzy starts documenting them

Comment: What is the include and exclude line say?

Comment: Check `undocumented.json` to see what you are missing and what jazzy is parsing